# How do I pull `static final` constants from a Java class into a Clojure namespace?

Tags: clojure, java-interop

I am trying to wrap a Java library with a Clojure binding.  One particular class in the Java library defines a bunch of static final constants, for example:

```
class Foo {
    public static final int BAR = 0;
    public static final int SOME_CONSTANT = 1;
    ...
}
```

I had a thought that I might be able to inspect the class and pull these constants into my Clojure namespace without explicitly `def`-ing each one.

For example, instead of explicitly wiring it up like this:

```
(def foo-bar Foo/BAR)
(def foo-some-constant Foo/SOME_CONSTANT)
```

I'd be able to inspect the `Foo` class and dynamically wire up `foo-bar` and `foo-some-constant` in my Clojure namespace when the module is loaded.

I see two reasons for doing this:

A) Automatically pull in new constants as they are added to the `Foo` class.  In other words, I wouldn't have to modify my Clojure wrapper in the case that the Java interface added a new constant.

B) I can guarantee the constants follow a more Clojure-esque naming convention

I'm not really sold on doing this, but it seems like a good question to ask to expand my knowledge of Clojure/Java interop.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly the macro *clojure.contrib.import-static* doesn't allow to import ***all*** static final fields. You must provide a list of fields to import.

This macro is a idiomatic wrapper for *import-static*:

```
(ns stackoverflow
  (:use clojure.contrib.import-static)
  (:import (java.lang.reflect Modifier)))

(defmacro import-static-fields
  "Imports all static final fields of the class as (private) symbols
  in the current namespace.

  Example: 
      user> (import-static-fields java.lang.Integer)
      #'user/TYPE
      user> MAX_VALUE
      2147483647

  Note: The class name must be fully qualified, even if it has already
  been imported."
  [class]
  (let [final-static-field? (fn [field]
                  (let [modifiers (.getModifiers field)]
                (and (Modifier/isStatic modifiers) (Modifier/isFinal modifiers))))
    static-fields (map #(.getName %)
               (filter
                final-static-field?
                (.. Class (forName (str class)) getFields)))]
    `(import-static ~class ~@static-fields)))
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a more concise all-clojure solution that uses `clojure.reflect/reflect`? http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.reflect/reflect

Answer (score 2):

*(This answer now includes two working solutions, one based on my initial idea with `intern` and one based on danlei's suggestion to use `c.c.import-static`. I guess I'll need to clean this up a bit later, but I can't spend more time on it now...)*

To extract static fields:

```
(filter #(bit-and java.lang.reflect.Modifier/STATIC (.getModifiers %))
        (.getFields YourClass))
```

<strike>Then map `#(intern *ns* (str "a-prefix-" (.getName %)) (.get YourClass nil))` across that sequence to obtain the value... Note that **this bit is untested** and, in particular, I'm not sure about that `nil` in `.get`; experiment with `java.lang.Field` and see what works with your class.</strike>

**Update 2:**

Ok, actually an `intern` based approach is not that bad readability-wise:

```
user> (map #(intern *ns* (symbol (str "integer-" (.getName %))) (.get % java.lang.Integer))
           (filter #(bit-and java.lang.reflect.Modifier/STATIC
                             (.getModifiers %))
                   (.getFields java.lang.Integer)))
(#'user/integer-MIN_VALUE #'user/integer-MAX_VALUE #'user/integer-TYPE #'user/integer-SIZE)
user> integer-MIN_VALUE
-2147483648
user> integer-MAX_VALUE
2147483647
user> integer-TYPE
int
user> integer-SIZE
32
```

**Update:** *(leaving the first update in place as an alternative solution)*

Combining danlei's knowledge of `clojure.contrib` with the above yields the following:

```
user> (map #(eval `(import-static java.lang.Integer ~(symbol (.getName %))))
           (filter #(bit-and java.lang.reflect.Modifier/STATIC
                             (.getModifiers %))
                   (.getFields java.lang.Integer)))
(#'user/MIN_VALUE #'user/MAX_VALUE #'user/TYPE #'user/SIZE)
user> MIN_VALUE
-2147483648
user> MAX_VALUE
2147483647
user> TYPE
int
user> SIZE
32
```

It uses `eval`... well, so what, it's hardly going to "kill performance" and it's actually fairly readable, which an elaborate expression using `intern` might not be. *(It's not so bad actually... :-))* <strike>If you prefer `intern`, though, at least the implementation of `import-static` can give you the proper ideas if my sketch above turns out to be incorrect somehow.</strike>

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but maybe clojure.contrib.import-static can do it.

Just checked: You will have to name the methods/fields when using import-static, but I'll leave this answer here because it might be helpful for people searching for related answers.

Comment: `c.c.import-static`, d'oh... Actually it's perfectly possible to take advantage of it here with the help of `eval`. I took the liberty of using it in an edit to my answer which gives an alternative approach to `intern` + Java reflection trickery.